# If not being caught disord.py

Tags: python, if-statement, discord, command, discord.py

```
def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and ctx.channel == m.channel

for index, i in enumerate(txtare):
    await ctx.send(f'What is the {txtare[index]}')
    try:

        variable = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=time_out, check=check)
        if variable.content == '!end':
            print(variable.content)
            return
        draw.text((x_axis[index], y_axis[index]),codecs.decode(str(variable.content), "unicode_escape"),(0,0,0),font=font2)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Time out!")
        return
```

why isn't it stopping neither recognizing that I wrote !end
So to explain 'variable' is what the discord user sends the bot. then I want to check the variable.content (the content of the message) and if it says !end the command should stop

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'm not familiar with discord.py; but would ```variable.content``` also include the ```\n```?

Comment: can you make it clear about your problem? what are you making, what have you've done and what is the problem ?

Comment: so the problem is, that I want the command to stop when I do !end, but unfortunately, the !end is not getting caught

Comment: yes @ewong the \n counts

Comment: so in essence, you could be comparing ```!end\n``` with ```!end``` which isn't the same.

Comment: let me make !end work first, then think about !end\n @ewong

Comment: what I mean is what if you did a ```if variable.content.strip() == '!end':```

Comment: just try printing `variable.content`, make sure it is the message that you want to wait for